# Is the tangent space to a critical submanifold a subspace of the kernel of the Hessian?

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, morse-theory, hessian-matrix

Trying to solve a question I have been faced with another question.

Let $f:M\to\mathbb{R}$ be a smooth function and $b\in \mathbb{R}$ a critical value of it. Now the following relation is true? 
$$T_qf^{-1}(b)\subset \operatorname{Ker}\operatorname{Hess}_qf=E_0,$$
where $E_0$ is the eigenspace associated to the eigenvalue $0$.

FYI: The Hessian of $f$ at a critical point $q$ is a symmetric bilinear form $\operatorname{Hess} f_q$ s.t. $\forall v,w\in T_qM$, 
    $$\operatorname{Hess} f_q(v,w)=V_q(W(f)),$$
    where $V,W$ are the extensions of $v$ and $w$ to vector fields such that $V_q=v$ and $W_q=w$.

I would appreciate any comment

Comment: The value $b\in\mathbb R$ cannot be a critical point for $f$, since $f$ is defined on $M$. You probably mean that $q\in M$ is a critical point and $f(q)=b$.

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro Yes yes! I wanted to write a critical value! I will correct it!

Comment: What do you mean by "the kernel of the Hessian" or "the eigenspace associated to the eigenvalue 0"? As you write, the Hessian is a symmetric bilinear form, which is *not* an endomorphism of the tangent space. Now, I can think of at least two non-equivalent definitions for the kernel, so I think you should elaborate here.

Comment: @AmitaiYuval Kernel of a symmetric bilinear form $Q:V\times V\to \mathbb{R}$ is the set

$ Ker(Q)=\{v \in V|Q(v,w)=0,\  \forall w \in V\}. $

Comment: @Majid Yes, this sounds like the right definition. And I guess this means that Giuseppe's answer is not a full one. And what about the eigenspace?

Comment: @AmitaiYuval Now consider the Hessian matrix. As it is symmetric there are eigenvalues and eigenvetors for it s.t. we can decompose the space.
For example see: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2295571/eigenvectors-and-eigenvalues-of-hessian-matrix

Comment: @AmitaiYuval Actually I am waiting for some more explanation by him :)

Comment: @Majid But the matrix depends on a choice of basis, and so, the eigenspaces and eigenvalues are not well-defined. The kernel is well-defined, of course, as you wrote three comments ago, but all other eigenspaces are not. This is why I find this terminology problematic when discussing bilinear forms.

Comment: @AmitaiYuval hmmmm! this is something else and as people talk about the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of the Hessian, it must be something famous! But let me ask it somewhere!

Comment: Of course, if you have a Riemannian metric, then you can think of any bilinear form as an endomorphism, and then all those terms make sense. But if there is no metric, then a bilinear form has a *signature*, and to the best of my understanding, this is all it has.

Comment: I do have a Riemnnain metric! But how you justify the being well-defined of the eigenvalues?

Comment: Oh, OK then. You didn't mention this metric... :) An inner product on a (finite dimensional) real vector space is, in particular, an isomorphism of the space with its dual. So, on a real inner product space, there is a full correspondence between endomorphisms and bilinear forms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the codimension-one case (where the level set is a hypersurface), you need to assume that $q$ is a critical *point*, not just that $b$ is a critical value. With this small change to your statement (which I assume you intended -
 it's necessary for the Hessian to be well-defined and thus for the claim to make sense at all), and a strong enough notion of submanifold (if you're allowing a self-intersecting immersion then $f(x,y) = xy$ is a counterexample), the result is true. Without loss of generality I will assume $b=0$ for simplicity.

Since we are assuming $f^{-1}\{0\}$ is a submanifold, we can choose coordinates $(x^1,\ldots,x^k,y^1,\ldots,y^{\ell}) : U \to B(0,1)$ on some neighbourhood $U \ni q$ so that $U \cap f^{-1}\{0\}=\{y=0\}$ and $q$ is the origin. In particular note that the $x^i$ restrict to give coordinates on the submanifold $\{y = 0\}.$ The fact that $q$ is a critical point gives us the extra information $\partial_{y_i} f(q) = 0$. Since Guiseppe's answer shows that $\partial_{x^i} \partial_{x^j} f(q) = 0$, it remains to show that $\partial_{x^i} \partial_{y^j} f(q) = 0$. The crucial fact we need to use is the following: not only is $f$ zero on $\{y = 0\}$, but it's nonzero everywhere else.

**Case 1:** $\ell = 1$, i.e. $f^{-1}\{0\}$ is a hypersurface and we have a single transverse coordinate $y=y^1$. It's not surprising this case is special, since it's the "expected" dimension (i.e. the dimension we would get from the regular value theorem if $0$ was a regular value). Since $f$ is a nonzero continuous function on the connected set $\{ y > 0 \}$, it has constant sign there; so combining this with the fact that it is zero on the boundary $\{ y = 0\}$ we conclude that $\partial_y f$ cannot change sign on $\{ y = 0\}$. Since $\partial_y f$ is zero at $q$, it is thus a smooth function with a local extremum at $q$, so it is critical there; i.e. $\partial_{x^i} \partial_y f = 0$ as desired.

**Case 2.** $\ell > 1$. In this case, the full complement $\{ y \ne 0 \}$ is connected; so $f$ has constant sign over $\{ y \ne 0 \}$ but is zero along $\{ y = 0\}$. Thus every point in $\{ y = 0 \}$ is a critical point of $f$, so $\partial_{y^j} f = 0 $ is constant on $\{ y = 0 \}$ and thus $\partial_{x^i} \partial_{y^j} f = 0$ as desired. Note that we didn't use the criticality assumption here - the function *must* be critical at this point to have such a small level set.

Comment: Great job. I linked to your answer in mine. Here I found interesting that you really need the assumption that $f^{-1}\{0\}$ is a submanifold (at least in a neighborhood of the critical point), if it just contains a submanifold then it's not enough.

Comment: Here the answer given by Anthony Carapetis together the one provided by Giuseppe Negro solve this problem,

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro: yes, it is somewhat counterintuitive that we can decrease the kernel of the Hessian while increasing the level set. I think the moral of the story is that critical points are weird!

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT**. There is an easy partial answer and a much more clever full answer, due to Anthony Carapetis.

---

**Easy partial answer**

> Assuming that $q\in N\subset f^{-1}\{b\}$ and that $N$ is a smooth submanifold of $M$,

then

> $\mathrm{Hess}_q(f)(v, w)=0$ for all $v, w\in T_q N$.

*Why partial?* Because this gives no information on $\mathrm{Hess}_q(f)(v, w)$ for $v\in T_qN$ and general $w\in T_qM$.

*Proof*.
If $\gamma$ is a curve passing through $q$ (i.e. $\gamma(0)=q$) and contained in $N\subset f^{-1}\{b\}$, then 
$$f(\gamma(t))=b, \qquad \forall t, $$
and differentiating this relation twice we obtain 
$$\mathrm{Hess}_{\gamma(t)}\, f(\dot{\gamma}(t), \dot{\gamma}(t)) + df(\gamma(t)) \ddot{\gamma}(t)=0.$$
Evaluating at $t=0$, using that $df(\gamma(0))=0$, this yields 
$$\mathrm{Hess}_{q}\, f(\dot{\gamma}(0), \dot{\gamma}(0))=0.$$

Since $\gamma$ was an arbitrary curve on $N$, this last equation shows that $\mathrm{Hess}_q\, f(v, v)=0$ for all $v\in T_qN$.

This is enough to conclude, because $\mathrm{Hess}_q\, f$ is a symmetric operator. Indeed, if $H\colon V\times V\to \mathbb R$ is a symmetric bilinear operator on a real vector space $V$, then $H(v, v)=0$ for all $v\in V$ implies that $H(v, w)=0$ for all $v, w\in V$, because of [the polarization identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polarization_identity#Symmetric_bilinear_forms).

---

**Full answer**

> Assuming that there exists an open set $U\subset M$ such that $q\in U$ and $$N=U\cap f^{-1}\{b\}\quad \text{is a smooth submanifold of }M, $$

then

> $\mathrm{Hess}_q(f)(v, w)=0$ for all $v\in T_q N$ and $w\in T_q M$.

*Proof*. This is Anthony's answer.

*Remark*. The main difference is in the result, which is stronger, because only one of the vectors is tangent to the level set $f^{-1}\{b\}$. The assumption is also slightly stronger, as it is assumed that the full level set has the structure of a submanifold (locally at least). In the easy case we merely assume that the level set contains a submanifold.

This is necessary to rule out the case of $f(x, y)=xy$. The origin of $\mathbb R^2$ is a critical point for $f$. The level set $f^{-1}\{0\}$ is not a submanifold in any neighborhood of the origin, due to self-intersection. We could consider the submanifold $N=\{(x, y)\in \mathbb R^2\ :\ y=0\}$, but then the result of the "**Full answer**" is false, as 
$$\mathrm{Hess}_{(0,0)} f( (1,0), (0,1) ) =1\ne 0, $$
even if $(1, 0)\in T_{(0,0)} N$.

Comment: @Majid: I am very interested in these things. Can I ask you in which context did you encounter this construction? I would really love to learn more.

Comment: Giuseppe Negro!
Super thanks for your nice solution. As you guessed, $f^{-1}(b)$ is a smooth submanifold. 
What about the equality $Ker Hess f =E_0$? Is it a clear fact?
I am trying to prove a theorem in my thesis and so I am working with the critical points and so the Hessian. I was proving a result for submanifolds and I faced this question :)

Comment: Just a small doubt about the last paragraph of your solution.

Comment: Here using the polarization, is this possible to conclude that $Hess_qf(v,w)=0,$ for every $v\in T_qf^{-1}(b)$ and for every $w\in T_qM?$

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro Majid has a good point here. You proved that $Hess f(v,w)=0$ for every $v$ and $w$ that are *both* tangent to the $b$-level set. I don't think this is enough to answer the question.